# Best practices for AWS cross account RDS snapshot share programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following AWS cross account use case where Account **A** belong
to another team and my team is the owner of account **B**.

1. AWS account **A** would like to copy/share snapshot of AWS RDS
   Oracle to AWS account **B**
2. Process/curate data by restoring snapshot in RDS instance and
   using AWS Step Functions workflow in account **B**
3. Share snapshot back to AWS account **A** from account **B**.

I am using `boto3` APIs and have working step functions code and I am looking for advice on solving step 1) and 3). I am thinking of asking account **A** team to write a Lambda which share snapshot and trigger Cloudwatch event which account **B** listens to  and another lambda to share snapshot back to account **A** programmatically. I am not sure if that is an optimal approach and if there is any better way.

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding code formatting to every library and technology name. It doesn't make it easier to read. Code formatting is for inline code, computer or console I/O, and possibly library names.

Answer (score 0):

For an "optimal approach" - Have you considered using AWS backup? If the accounts are under the same organization AWS backup can do this all for you.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/manage-cross-account.html

and here: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/amazon-rds-backup-restore-using-aws-backup/